# how to clear TextInput focus in React Native? (Android)

Tags: android, react-native

how to clear TextInput focus in React Native? (Android)

I have look for an API here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#content

But no result...

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this should work. Add the onFocus as a prop to your `TextInput` . This is assuming you have a state variable called text, and that the `TextInput` takes its value from that state variable.

```
<TextInput 
   ...
   onFocus= {() => this.setState({text : ''})}
   value={this.state.text}/>
```

Comment: Thanks although I have give up the android react-native and using the native now. Compared with iOS version the android version is really ... you know. And I do not see the point of using react-native when learning Android is faster and more flexible.